# Using dict values, problems with 0 and string in one column

Tags: python, pandas

this is my code- it adds data from dict to a df, creating a new col. Code was working with first row of source df ( only string). Second and following cols consist of A,B,C,D,E,F and 0. Column is 'object',  I tried to change to 'string' and replaced  0 with a minus, so far no success.

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

````
def get_dict(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5):
    collect = []
    result = None
    if c1 in dict:
        col1 = dict[c1]
    else:
        col1 = None
    if c2 in dict:
        col2 = dict[c2]
    else:
        col2 = None
    if c3 in dict:
        col3 = dict[c3]
    else:
        col3 = None
    if c4 in dict:
        col4 = dict[c4]        
    else:
        col4 = None
    if c5 in dict:
        col5 = dict[c5]
    else:
        col5 = None
    collect = [col1,col2,col3,col4,col5]
    collection = ','.join(['' if i is None else i for i in collect])
    
    return collection

df1['Perimeter Defense']=df1.apply(lambda k: get_dict(k['1'],k['2'],k['3'],k['4'],k['5'] ),axis=1)

#Incomplete dict

dict= {'Shengelia': 'A',
  'Kurbanov': 'F',
  'James': 'B',
  'Clyburn': 'B',
  'Voigtmann': 'C',
  'Hilliard': 'B',
  'Hackett': 'E',
  'Milutinov': '0',
  'Bolomboy': '0',
  'Strelnieks': 'E',
  'Lundberg': 'E',
  'Antonov': 'D',
  'Ukhov': 'A',
  'Eric': '0',
  'Khomenko': 'A',
  'Pangos': 'A',
  'Baron': 'A',
  'Thomas': '0'}```

Full error message

   TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-370-603fced3dd5d> in <module>
     27     return collection
     28 
---> 29 df1['Perimeter Defense']=df1.apply(lambda k: get_dict(k['1'],k['2'],k['3'],k['4'],k['5'] ),axis=1)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   7766             kwds=kwds,
   7767         )
-> 7768         return op.get_result()
   7769 
   7770     def applymap(self, func, na_action: Optional[str] = None) -> DataFrame:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
    183             return self.apply_raw()
    184 
--> 185         return self.apply_standard()
    186 
    187     def apply_empty_result(self):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    274 
    275     def apply_standard(self):
--> 276         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    277 
    278         # wrap results

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    288             for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    289                 # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 290                 results[i] = self.f(v)
    291                 if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    292                     # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because

<ipython-input-370-603fced3dd5d> in <lambda>(k)
     27     return collection
     28 
---> 29 df1['Perimeter Defense']=df1.apply(lambda k: get_dict(k['1'],k['2'],k['3'],k['4'],k['5'] ),axis=1)

<ipython-input-370-603fced3dd5d> in get_dict(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)
     23         col5 = None
     24     collect = [col1,col2,col3,col4,col5]
---> 25     collection = ','.join(['' if i is None else i for i in collect])
     26 
     27     return collection

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
````

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: You shouldn't name your variable `dict`. It is a built-in function that creates a new dictionary object, naming your variable like that will override it.

Comment: And your code doesn't work because `join` expects an iterable of string. you should write `str(i)` in the `if` to fix it

Answer (score 1):

For using `join`, each data element should be of type `str`, you can cast your `int` into string in the list comprehension, like this

```
collection = ','.join(['' if i is None else str(i) for i in collect])
```